# Is operator $\hat{O}_{\alpha}:|\phi,\psi\rangle\mapsto |e^{i~\alpha[\phi,\psi]}~\phi,e^{-i~\alpha[\phi,\psi]}~\psi\rangle$ unitary?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, hilbert-space

Is the operator $\hat O_{\alpha}$ which is defined in the following a unitary operator?

Operator $\hat O_{\alpha}$ is supposed to act on composite states with two explicit components, such that

$$| \phi, \psi \rangle \mapsto \hat O_{\alpha} | \phi, \psi \rangle := | e^{i~\alpha[ \phi, \psi ]}~\phi, e^{-i~\alpha[ \phi, \psi ]}~\psi \rangle,$$

where $\phi$ and $\psi$ denote the two explicit components, and $\alpha[ \phi, \psi ]$ is a generally non-zero "phase value" as some specific function of the two explicit components.

Is operator $\hat O_{\alpha}$ unitary for any arbitrary "phase function $\alpha$", or perhaps only for some suitable specific cases?

Might there be any other reasons to argue that operator $\hat O_{\alpha}$ is not a valid operator to be considered in [quantum-mechanics](/questions/tagged/quantum-mechanics)?

Comment: What is a "state with two explicit components"? Do you mean an element of the *tensor product*? (note that the ordinary Cartesian product is *not* a suitable product for spaces of states, see [my answer here](http://physics.stackexchange.com/a/148429/50583))

Comment: ACuriousMind: "_What is a "state with two explicit components"?_" -- Well, my question is motivated by (and aiming to dispute) [this answer; especially its **EDIT**](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/149490/question-about-the-no-clone-theorem/149794#149794). Correspondingly, the two components would be Bob's positron state (say $|\psi\rangle$) together with some suitable separate "blank" state (say $|\phi\rangle$, for instance the state of some particular proton). Together, formally: $|\phi,\psi\rangle$. "_Do you mean an element of the tensor product?_" -- You tell me, please ...

Comment: What is behind your question? I see that you are preoccupied by the n-cloning theorem.

Comment: @user12262: What is behind your question? I see that you are preoccupied by the n-cloning theorem. The operator exp(iα[ϕ,ψ]) is unitary if its action can be reversed i.e. exp(iα[ϕ,ψ])† = exp(iα[ϕ,ψ])^(-1)

Comment: @Sofia: "_[...] unitary if its action can be reversed_" -- Well, then: does the suggested operator $\hat O_{\alpha}$ satisfy that? For arbitrary "phase functions $\alpha[ \phi, \psi ]$"? Or only for some? Also: note that the operator is defined for a **composite state**, as I've tried to describe ... (It'd be nice if you could demonstrate and discuss this as an answer. My own focus had rather been on [the property of unitary operators to "preserve the inner product"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unitary_operator).)